# Two-part sci fi novel that has an almost sentient star

Tags: story-identification, novel

At the end of the first part, the hero merges with a sentient star to stop it from going nova. His friend (an alien) along with the assassin (that tries to kill him in the start) also get sucked into this merger. All of them merge with the star and prevent it from going nova. In the end they create a sort of wormhole/bridge through space-time.

The second part is about a vessel traveling through this bridge and facing a threat from bat-like aliens that pull passengers into the void while in hyper/metaspace.  The protagonist is a little girl. There is a robot common to both these stories.

It is not the *Starchild* trilogy or *Whipping Star* by Frank Herbert.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Nice start, but hopefully you can remember a few more details to [edit] into the question; there's a [guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/101407) of things that you might also be able to add.

Comment: Thanks @DavidW. I'll see if I can make any changes based on the guide.

Answer (score 1):

I found it. It's the Starstream series by Jeffrey A. Carver. Yay for me!!

Comment: For the record, you didn't find it. This Tachyon guy did; https://www.sffchronicles.com/threads/539059/